# How to use debugger on perl script executed by "exec"

Tags: perl

I trying to figure out how a Perl script which is doing test status reporting, is working. The script executes another piece of perl script via `exec`. I am able single step through code in first script but when it hits `exec`, the script executed by `exec` runs till completion. Is there a way by which I will be able single step and look at variables in the script executed  by `exec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below to the script which is being called with `exec`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -d
```